# href getting added to current url

Tags: php, .htaccess, href

My site url is localhost/projectX/

When I click on "About" as per below code, my url becomes:
localhost/projectX/about/about

```
<div id="page-header">
    <h1><?=$data['app_title'];?></h1>
    <p><a href="home">Home</a> | <a href="about/about">About</a> | <a href="logout">Logout</a></p>
</div>
```

Now if i click on "Home", it add on to current url to become:
localhost/projectX/about/about/home

Whereas, I want it to be:
localhost/projectX/home

If I add trailing slash to href tag i.e., `<a href="/home">Home</a>`, it redirects to localhost/home/ and gives error.

I am using two htaccess files.
First one redirects to Public folder of my MVC structure

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule     ^$     public/     [L]
    RewriteRule     (.*)   public/$1/   [L]
</IfModule>
```

In Public folder I have another htaccess which is as follows

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

PLease help me out with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably like to read this article: http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/

I think you could use `/projectX/home`, which will work from any folder.

Or from `localhost/projectX/about/about` you could use `../../home` which navigates up 2 folders and then to home.

The article I linked should be able to explain how these work better than I can.